# Not able to include fmt/format.h header only (GCC-12)

Tags: c++, c++20

I could not include (could not compile to be exact) fmt/format with GCC-12.

file 1: format

```
#pragma once
#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include "fmt/format.h"
namespace std
{
    using fmt::format;
    using fmt::format_error;
    using fmt::formatter;
}
```

file 2: helloworld.cpp

```
// helloworld.cpp
import <iostream>;

#include "format"

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::format("There are {} ways I love you.", 219) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Commands:

```
g++-12 -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header iostream
g++-12 -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts helloworld.cpp
```

Error message:

```
fmt/format.h:1010:54: internal compiler error: in cxx_eval_call_expression, at cp/constexpr.cc:2835
 1010 |   return {result.grouping, Char(result.thousands_sep)};
      |                                                      ^
```

OS - WSL2/Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

fmt - fmt-8.1.1

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First: Adding declarations to `std` causes undefined behavior (with few specific exceptions). Don't do that. Second: An internal compiler error is always a bug in the compiler. You should check whether it has been reported yet and if not, report it, but with the code reduced to a [mre]. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/ and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.

Comment: An internal compiler error is always some form of compiler bug. Since the code in question isn't yours, the most you can do is report it or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: Thanks guys. Adding declaration was meant to have a drop-in replacement for std::format down the road. While doing that, I was also thinking something was wrong with the compiler.